# Does analyzer work with ARC?

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

Since converting my project to ARC, it seems the analyzer is a bit in denial.  I'm getting a ton of these warnings:

```
Object leaked: object allocated and stored into 'object name' is not referenced later in this execution path and has a retain count of +1.
```

A bit confused as I don't think I would be able to release a object even if I tried.  Here is a slice of example code where I'm seeing this happen:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you're actually compiling with ARC? Because the analyzer certainly doesn't think so. Try inserting a [request release] in there and see if the compiler flags that as an error. If it doesn't, then you don't have ARC on.

Remember, it's possible to turn ARC on or off on a per-file basis. To check this, go to your Compile Sources build phase, find the file in question, and the second column is a list of per-file compilation flags. If this contains `-fno-objc-arc` then ARC is turned off for that file. Of course, you should also double-check that ARC is, in fact, turned on for the target as a whole.

Comment: That was totally it!  Thanks so much for the guidance on this one.  I suspected that was the case but had no idea how to check.  Thanks a million!